# The req.ip can't be changed in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to change the value of req.ip in express framework of node.js but req.ip still remains the same value while self-defined memeber ex: req.my_var works; I can't figure out the difference of these two cases... Any idea?

```
var truncateIPAddress = function (req, res, next) {
  req.ip = req.ip.substring(0,30); // still the same value in other route
  req.my_var = 'test'; //it works
  next();
}
app.use(truncateIPAddress);
..........
app.use('/', index);
```

Comment: Maybe its a constant try assigning the truncated value to another var.

Comment: The request.ip is a getter without a setter so you can't override it's value, without overriding the getter.
Little piece of advice, create your middleware of you want to replace and override the getter for every request.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `req.ip` provides the client's IP address in Node JS using Express. As per your code you are trying to overwrite the value of `req.ip`.

This will work for your `truncateIPAddress` function but it's overwritten value will be reset again because of its scope.

So you have to choose a global variable and replace the value globally and use that global variable on required positions.

Thank you!

Comment: I did another test in truncateIPAddress that print the value of req.ip in function truncateIPAddress after I set req.ip to another value. However, the req.ip value is still the same(i.e. req.ip = '1234'; console.log(req.ip) //not '1234', it's still origin value)..... I'm confused. Is req.ip kind of read-only value?

Comment: whenever you call req.ip, it always get ip address using request headers, so it can not be changed. In case if you wants to change and use then , first store it in any global variable and then use. As I have suggested in answer.

Comment: Please let me know if you have further any query for the same

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can. Here is the code to do it:

```
Object.defineProperty(app.request, 'ip', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () { return this.get('Client-IP') }
})
```